# Is the following sentence grammatical & natural?

Tags: grammar

> The fastest way to discourage individuals from leaving their waste unrecycled is that they be informed it is against the law.

Isn't it better:

> ...is to inform them it is against the law.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original sentence is not necessarily grammatically incorrect, however it does not sound natural.

It would be better to say something like:

- The fastest way to discourage individuals from leaving their waste unrecycled is to inform them that it is against the law.
- The fastest way to discourage individuals from leaving their waste unrecycled is by informing them that it is against the law.

I would also add that "leaving their waste unrecycled" also sounds unnatural. As a native speaker I would personally say something like "the fastest way to discourage individuals from not recycling" or "the fastest way to encourage individuals to recycle"